# Class/Interface to encapsulate OSGi bundle in file system

Tags: java, osgi

Is there something in the OSGi framework api that encapsulates a bundle not installed in a container? Basically, something that would take a File and generate an object with getSymbolicName(), getExportedPackages(), getBundleVersion(), etc for a bundle in the filesystem.

I see [Bundle](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html) but the doc says in the first sentence:

> An installed bundle in the Framework.

So this interface has methods that don't make sense for a bundle that's not installed, just sitting there in the filesystem, which is what I need. It has a `start()` method for example, which doesn't make sense outside of a container. Same with `getBundleId()`

I need one and I want to know if there's a standard one before I create my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundle is for an INSTALLED bundle, as you say. It can be used inside an OSGi container for a bundle that is handled by the container. However, if you need the information you mentioned, it is very easy to get with a small function.

- Create a new JarFile(fileName)
- Read the manifest
- Read the values from the Manifest and use the org.osgi.framework.Constants interface as the parameter of the manifest.getMainAttributes().get(key) function.

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/everit-org/eosgi-maven-plugin/blob/82e1734e67687a2aeb0ba67d072686f7626fefab/src/main/java/org/everit/osgi/dev/maven/AbstractOSGIMojo.java#L91) in the checkBundle() function (from line 91)

**EDIT**

You can use JarInputStream if the bundle comes from somewere else but not from the file system.

You could try take out the [felix manifest parser class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.framework/2.0.5/org/apache/felix/framework/util/manifestparser/ManifestParser.java) (or equinox or Knopflerfish equivalent) into a standalone project and share it with the community ;-).

Comment: Thank you Balazs. I know how to extract all that, except the Constants interface i didn't know about, and that i will now use. thanks for that. But the answer to my question is then, there isn't one, agree? It's just that if i create my own encapsulation I might be missing things that I just don't use, like getFragmentsHost. So i was wondering if there's a feature-complete api already in the standard. Something more OO than just strings from manifest entries, e.g. an ExportedPackage class with a getVersion(), getUses(), etc instead of me parsing a string

Comment: No parser in the API. The API is more about interfaces and constants than classes with implementations. As much as I remember, I checked how equinox and how felix parses the MANIFEST.MF and both had their own simple solutions. It was years ago so I do not remember the class names but it was not hard to find. Just push "ctrl+alt+h" in eclipse on any of the constant values when felix or equinox is on the classpath. There will be not many places where e.g. Fragment-Host constant is used from.

Comment: Remember that bundles are not necessarily present in the file system at all. They are loaded from an InputStream that can come from anywhere.

Comment: In that case a JarInputStream instead of a JarFile can help to get the Manifest data. I think Hilikus is also looking for some general solution that parses Import-Package, Export-Package and other complex property values. Something like http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix/trunk/framework/src/main/java/org/apache/felix/framework/util/manifestparser/ManifestParser.java but in a standalone project. Well, I do not know if such a project exists.

Comment: [Bnd](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Bnd), when used as a library, includes lots of utilities for parsing manifest entries.